# array subscript is not an integer questions

Tags: c, arrays

hi i'm new to c and have never run into this error before and i'm a little confused as i dont believe i have declared any int's in my program at all however on likes 13, 14, 22, 23, 24, 35, and 40 i get array subscript is not an integer my code is as follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>

 int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
double mint[8];
double gum[8];
double count = 1.0,num,sum=0.0;

while(count <= 8)
{
    printf("please enter a number");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    mint[count]=num;
    printf("%d\n",mint[count] );
    count++;
}

count = 1;

while(count<=8)
{
    sum += mint[count];
    gum[count] = sum;
    printf("%d\n",gum[count] );
    count++;
}

count = 1.0;
sum = 1.0;

while(count<=8)
{
    while(sum<=8)
    {
        printf("%d",mint[sum] );
        sum++;
        if (sum==8)
            printf("\n");
    }
    printf("%d",gum[count] );
    count++;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `i dont believe i have declared any int's in my program` Yeah, exactly. That's what the error is moaning about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
scanf("%d",&num);
```

`d` expects a pointer to `int` not a pointer to `double`. Use `lf` if the argument is a pointer to `double`.

Same for `printf`:

```
printf("%d\n",mint[count] );
```

`d` expects an `int` not a `double`.

Comment: That's not the OP's problem.  I mean, it is a problem.  But not the one he's asking about.

Answer (score 5):

You can't index an array with a `double` value. What if `count` is 2.4 for example?

Therefore you have to use an integer (`int` for instance).

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
double count = 1.0
```

then

```
mint[count]=num;
```

You cannot have indexes into an array that is a double - needs to be a integral number

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is referring to your use of `double` type to access an array:

```
mint[count]
```

Where `count` is a `double`.

Make `count` and `sum` be `int` to get rid of the warning.

As other answerers have noted - your program has several other problems as well.  You might want to check out a beginner's tutorial someplace.

Comment: Or, preferably, a peer-reviewed book. Poor coding like this comes from reading "beginner's tutorials" that you found "someplace".